# How can I find the largest key in a cache

Tags: ignite

I have a cache () that has keys that increase (although not necessarily in sequence e.g. 1002, 1003, 1020, 1100)

I'm using the .Net version of Ignite (which is a wrapper around the java version)

Right now I'm getting the entire set and querying the results using Linq.

How can retrieve the largest key efficiently without using Linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An efficient way is to use SQL (with a proper index if the number is part of the value).

You can continue to use LINQ with Ignite LINQ provider to keep the code clean:
https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/linq

Simple example with `int` keys:

```
        var cfg = new CacheConfiguration("cache-name", new QueryEntity(typeof(int), typeof(int)));
        var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, int>(cfg);

        cache[1] = 1;
        cache[3] = 3;

        var max = cache.AsCacheQueryable().Max(e => e.Key);
```

This is going to be translated to SQL and executed efficiently by Ignite without loading entire data set locally.